# No "Disable touchpad while typing" checkbox in Mouse & Trackpad settings

Tags: 16.04, gnome, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Gigabyte Aero with an Elantech touchpad. The output of xinput looks like:

```
david@Aero:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Bluetooth Mouse M557                      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ E-Signal Keyboard                         id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ E-Signal Keyboard                         id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Chicony USB 2.0 Camera                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Edit: Details from xinput on the touchpad:

```
david@Aero:~$ xinput list-props 17
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (168):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (170): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (296): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (297):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (298):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (299):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (326):  127, 3061, 112, 1973
    Synaptics Finger (327): 1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (328):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (329):   167
    Synaptics Tap Durations (330):  180, 100, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (331):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (332):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (333):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (334):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (335): 76, 76
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (336): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (337):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (338): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.052507, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (339):    1
    Synaptics Locked Drags (340):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (341):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (342): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (343):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (344): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (345):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (346): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (347):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (348): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (349):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (350): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (351):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (352): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (353):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (354):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (355):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (356):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (357): 31, 31
    Synaptics Area (358):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (359):  1594, 0, 1709, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (360): 19, 19
    Device Product ID (285):    2, 14
    Device Node (286):  "/dev/input/event8"
```

Gnome (via gnome-settings-daemon?) starts up an instance of syndaemon on login:

```
david@Aero:~$ ps aux | grep syndaemon | grep -v grep
david     4275  0.0  0.0  22372  1164 ?        S    08:35   0:00 syndaemon -i 1.0 -t -K -R
```

However the '-t' option is problematic on my machine. If I `killall syndaemon` and re-run it with my preferred options (`-i 1.5 -K -d`) it works great. Unfortunately, setting my startup app's command to `killall syndaemon && syndaemon ...` doesn't actually kill Gnome's instance, likely because the startup applications run before Gnome runs its instance.

The generally-accepted way to disable Gnome's instance of syndaemon launched on login is to "Uncheck the 'Disable while typing' option in Mouse & Trackpad settings" - but for me that option does not appear. I'm guessing this is because I don't have a Synaptics touchpad?

[image: Screenshot of Mouse and Touchpad Settings]

(Another laptop I have, a Samsung 9 series with an Elantech touchpad running 14.04LTS, *does* show the checkbox.)

So I need one of the following:

- A way to disable Gnome's on-login launch of syndaemon without unchecking that box, or
- A way to make the box appear so I can uncheck it?

Thanks!

Comment: lease [edit] your question and add output of `xinput list-props 16` terminal command.

Comment: Whoops, looks like I had a config change somewhere in there and added the wrong ID. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a usable workaround, but remain interested in learning if there is a "proper" way to do this....

I renamed `/usr/bin/syndaemon` to `/usr/bin/syndaemon.priv` and invoked the latter in my startup application command line. Gnome can't find the original syndaemon executable and its invocation fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you install `touchpad-indicator`, it has functions to disable the touchpad whilst typing, and many settings that you can configure.

If you don't see `touchpad-indicator` in your Synaptic, you can go to `https://www.atareao.es/apps/touchpad-indicator-para-ubuntu/` for more information.

You can also add his repository by entering these commands in terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator`

Cheers, Al